# execute inline js loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi and thanks for stopping.

i already solved my problem, but on my own, so i just want to share my solution and maybe someone has a more elegant way to solve it. maybe its just nice as it is.

so im loading some html via jquery.ajax() and the dataType is html.
sometimes a video is placed inside, and the most elegant way for me to embed this, is the jwplayers js embed code, that looks like this:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        flashplayer: "/player.swf",
        image: "/image.jpg",
        autostart: true,
        'controlbar': 'none',
        file: "/video.m4v",
        width: 752,
        height: 416
    });
</script>
```

now if i load this, nothing happens, the js just doesnt get executed.

so i ended up putting the js WITHOUT the script tags into a div.

```
<div id="vc">
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        ...
    });
</div>
```

and then in my ajaxComplete() call i simply move the stuff out of the div and place it in between two script tags.

```
if ($("#vc").text() !== "") {
    var vjs = $("#vc").text();
    $("#vc").empty().html("<script>"+vjs+"</script>");
}
```

Comment: Javascript eval() the function?

Answer (score 2):

Define a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var embedPlayer = function() {
        jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            flashplayer: "/player.swf",
            image: "/image.jpg",
            autostart: true,
            'controlbar': 'none',
            file: "/video.m4v",
            width: 752,
            height: 416
        });
    };
    embedPlayer();
</script>
```

and then in the success callback you could call this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#container').html(result);
        embedPlayer();
    }
});
```

Comment: oh, i told him to use eval() instead of calling a function! stupid me!

Comment: i tried this yesterday (and now again), but i get an "embedPlayer is not defined" if i call embedPlayer() on success.

Comment: @Kheu using eval is no more dangerous that what OP is currently doing nor more dangerous that blindly wrapping the code in a function. That is to say, they are all dangerous.

Comment: @honk31 - I'm not surprised. If adding code to the page by setting innerhtml doesn't execute the function call inside the code, then I don't see why it would define a function inside the code.

Comment: If the parameters, or the whole script must be loaded dynamically, then, there is not much of choice, but to use eval()

Answer (score 1):

although it is not recommended, user eval();

```
if ($("#vc").text() !== "") {
    eval($("#vc").text())
}
```